# Issue of loading PDF hosted on IIS 8.5

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I host a static folder containing some large PDFs (~7000 kb) on IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2. When I open the PDF in Chrome, the following message always shows first. I have to reload the page many times to display the PDF correctly.

[image]

Then I checked the network log using Chrome developer tool and found out the failed requests have Status Code "206 Partial Content". See the following screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone have similar issue as me? Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue:
1. Use the latest version of Chrome
2. In google chrome, you can change the default chrome pdf viewer to Adobe pdf viewer plugin.

Here I find the option my Google Chrome Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Please recheck ... PDF switch setting is available on Latest version of Google Chrome.

Comment: It looks like the new Chrome does not provide an option switching PDF viewer :-(

Comment: Did you try in older one ?

Comment: New version of google chrome provide the pdf  switch. Please check again.